# How do I sort to find the top 5 out of 34 elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I have 34 elements, but I only need to know which are the top 5 ranked.

I am using a comparison "A versus B" type questionaire across all 34 elements.

Right now, it isn't dynamic, so I cannot change the questions based on the prior questions.

- What is the minimum number of questions in the questionaire I can ask?
- What is the sorting algorithm you would use?

Right now I am using manualation and using Excel, but want to know how to eventually do it in Ruby for a basic Rails app.

Comment: What do you mean by "questionaire"?  Is this is a question that is answered by a human user, or is it a question that can be answered by a computer, (e.g. by comparing two integers to see which is greater)?

Answer (score 4):

If you just have simple integers, floats or strings, you can sort an array easily:

```
a = [ 3,3,1,6,2,8 ]
a.sort # => [1,2,3,3,6,8]
```

But this sorts ascending.

To sort descending, you can do:

```
a.sort {|x,y| y <=> x } # => [8,6,3,3,2,1]
```

or

```
a.sort.reverse # => [8,6,3,3,2,1]
```

Then to get the first 5 elements, just use:

```
a.sort.reverse.take(5) # => [8,6,3,3,2]
```

If the elements you are sorting are actually structures, you can change the code inside a sort_by block to account for that easily, eg:

```
a = [{:score => 5, :name => "Bob"}, {:score => 51, :name => "Jane"}, \
     {:score => 15, :name => "Joe"}, {:score => 23, :name => "John"}, \
     {:score => 35, :name => "Sam"}, {:score => 1, :name => "Rob"}]

a.sort_by{|x| x[:score] }.reverse.take(5)
# => [{:score => 51, :name => "Jane"},{:score => 35, :name => "Sam"},...]
```

Comment: It might be more readable to do: `a.sort_by{|x| x[:score]}.reverse[0..4]`

Comment: Thanks, changed. I like `take` more than `[0..4]`

Comment: `reverse` on a large array can be costly. Negate the value in the `sort_by` or reverse the order of the comparison in the `sort` clause.

Comment: well, `reverse` is no more costly than `sort`. If you really wanted performance, you wouldn't use `sort` which is `O(n log n)`, you would have to use the C++ equivalent of `nth_element` - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/nth_element/, or if you wanted the 5 sorted, then C++ equivalent of `partial_sort`